# While testing i want to insert multiple values in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am testing some sql code that can take in multiple values into it, they are then compared by using an 'IN' statement. How do I simulate this for testing. Heres what I'm Using but it returns nothing, which is incorrect, because when I send in multiple values in my SSRS report, it works. I'd like @item to simulate what its getting from SSRS when the report is run.

```
Declare
@item VarChar(100)

Set @item = ('1003932,1003933,1003934')




SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTNAME,
    ISNULL(NAME, LOGCREATEDBY) AS 'Modified By'
    ,b.ITEMID as 'Item Id'
    ,[PRICE_NEW] as 'New Price'
    ,[PRICE_OLD] as 'Old Price'
    ,[PRICEUNIT_NEW] as 'New Unit Price'
    ,[PRICEUNIT_OLD] as 'Old Unit Price'
    ,LOGCREATEDDATE as 'Created Date' 
    ,(Select TOP 1 INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL From INVENTTRANS Where INVENTTRANS.ITEMID = @item order by INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL desc) As 'LastInvoice'
FROM PMF_INVENTTABLEMODULELOG AS b
    LEFT JOIN USERINFO ON ID = LOGCREATEDBY
    LEFT JOIN INVENTTABLE AS a on a.ITEMID in (@item)
WHERE b.ITEMID in (@item)
order by LOGCREATEDDATE  desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
Declare @item table
( item varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @item
SELECT '1003932' union all
SELECT '1003933' union all
SELECT '1003934']


SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTNAME,
    ISNULL(NAME, LOGCREATEDBY) AS 'Modified By'
    ,b.ITEMID as 'Item Id'
    ,[PRICE_NEW] as 'New Price'
    ,[PRICE_OLD] as 'Old Price'
    ,[PRICEUNIT_NEW] as 'New Unit Price'
    ,[PRICEUNIT_OLD] as 'Old Unit Price'
    ,LOGCREATEDDATE as 'Created Date' 
    ,(Select TOP 1 INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL From INVENTTRANS Where INVENTTRANS.ITEMID = @item order by INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL desc) As 'LastInvoice'
FROM PMF_INVENTTABLEMODULELOG AS b
    LEFT JOIN USERINFO ON ID = LOGCREATEDBY
    LEFT JOIN INVENTTABLE AS a on a.ITEMID in (@item)
WHERE b.ITEMID in (SELECT item from @item)
order by LOGCREATEDDATE  desc
```

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done like this.

I'd suggest that you insert the values into a table variable,

```
declare @items_table table (id int);
insert @items_table values ('1003932'),('1003933'),('1003934');
```

and then change the where clause into

```
WHERE b.ITEMID in (SELECT id FROM @items_table)
```

Or you can just simply modify the where clause:

```
WHERE b.ITEMID in ('1003932','1003933','1003934')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue, especially when working with multi-parameter variables being populated from SSRS.  Here's a solution I found in some legacy code that I think is pretty useful.  The link for the function is from  Michelle Ufford at sqlfool.com.  Link: http://sqlfool.com/2011/05/string-parsing-function/

```
DECLARE @item VARCHAR(100)
SET @item = '1003932,1003933,1003934'

DECLARE @tblItems AS TABLE
(
    Item VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO @tblItems
        ( Item )
SELECT stringValue
FROM Database.dbo.dba_parseString_udf(@item,',')

SELECT * FROM @tblItems
```

Inserting `SELECT Item FROM @tblItems` in place of `@item` in your code should do the trick.  Best of all when using this approach, it makes it easy to populate the query when you want to test the data in SSMS, as you can just copy the parameters that you want from SSRS parameter box.  And this code doesn't need to be modified at all with SSRS, so that commenting out the first two lines of code will make your code ready to accept multiple parameters from SSRS.
NOTE: apparently this only works when you are using a stored procedure on in SSMS to encapsulate the code.  When you select more than one parameter when using the query string in SSRS, you get an error that reads:

> Procedure or function Database.dbo.dba_parseString_udf has too many arguments specified.

It looks like the arguments are passed by a string to a stored procedure but passed as an array to the string query.